# Java cannot load a class that is in a package

Tags: java, classpath

When I try to execute a Doc class that is located in a package, I get the error message: `Could not find or load main class Doc.java`

The class is in a test.foo package. I compile it then enter `java test.foo.Doc` and get the error. I tried setting the classpath to the current directory using `java -cp *; test.Doc` but it doesn't work either. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm also already in the directory where the class is located.
What am I doing wrong? My CLASSPATH environment variable points to the current directory as well.

Comment: Could you post the directory tree of your project, as well as the relevant code snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when your Doc.java is placed as:

```
./test/foo/Doc.java
javac ./test/foo/Doc.java
java test.foo.Doc
```

Comment: I missed that part. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy that I could help. You could be nice and accepted as a correct answer, which would be my first on stackoverflow.